# Is it work-for-hire if the hirer doesn't own copyright on collective work?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, derivative-work, copyright-transfer, work-for-hire

Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_for_hire#Law_in_the_United_States, work done by an an *independent contractor* may qualify under *work-for-hire* if it's *a contribution to a collective work*.

But what if the hirer doesn't actually own the copyright to the collective work?!  E.g., if it's a FL/OSS project that the contractor was hired to modify and extend, and the copyright on the existing collective work is owned by a third party?

Does this nuance at all alter the determination on whether or not a given work would qualify as work-for-hire when commissioned by a party that has no reasonable existing copyright stake on the collective work in question?

Comment: Even if the *existing* code is copyrighted by a third party, wouldn't the newly contributed code still be copyrighted by its author?  The author may eventually want to transfer that copyright to the third party, but that's separate.

Comment: @NateEldredge but who's the author?  And why would the author want to transfer it to a third-party?

Comment: The author may be either the person who actually wrote the new code, or their employer if it is a work for hire.  My point is that the fact that it's supposed to be a contribution to other code already copyrighted by someone else isn't directly relevant.  If it's for an open source project, the programmer or their employer *might* want to transfer the copyright to the project maintainer (so that all the code belongs to one person), but as I said, that would be separate.

Comment: @NateEldredge there is no employee/employer relationship at stake; and my question is about determining who the actual author of the code is; it does not at all help for folks to be replying with ***"the programmer or their X"*** (with inapplicable values for X at that) when a determination of which one it is, is the exact point of the question.  I don't think you understand the question based on your comments.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding FL/OSS, I don't think the example given is typically a collective work in most cases. Collective works are specifically defined in [17 USC 101](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/101) as (my emphasis): "a work, such as a periodical issue, anthology, or encyclopedia, in which a number of **contributions, constituting separate and independent works** in themselves, are assembled into a collective whole."

Answer (score 1):

If the derivative work is made **without** the permission of the copyright holder or not under fair use/dealing (i.e. it is an infringing work) then the original owner is legally the owner of the derivative work.

If the derivative work is made **with** the permission of the copyright holder (including the terms of any licence) or under fair use/dealing (i.e. it is **not** an infringing work) then the author is the owner of the copyright. If the author is subject to the 'work-for-hire' rule then the employer of the author of the is the copyright holder.

Comment: Note that in a work-for-hire situation the employer is legally the **author** as well as the copyright holder. This can make a difference. For example, the life+70 term of copyright will not apply, instead the 95-year corporate term will apply (under US law).

Comment: @DavidSiegel that’s us specific - in most other jurisdictions the author is still the author and the term is based on them. Most jurisdictions have (non-)transferable moral rights that belong to the author, not the owner.

Comment: @DaleM but the question is specific to the US; there is no "employment" relationship between any parties, either; I explicitly mentioned the part from Wikipedia on US law that I have the question about, because the whole work-for-hire exception seemed weird to me when the contractor is independent, and not an employee, yet seemingly the employee-is-not-an-author jurisdiction is being applied nonetheless to non-employees.  I think all examples from Wikipedia seem to indicate "exceptions" of some sort for the film and education industry; I was curious whether they extend to OSS model.